# Flutter iOS device: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1024

Tags: android, flutter

Problem when connect to real iOS device using **Flutter** in Android Studio.

> `"Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1024"`

Searched up and restart the device, switch to master channel seems not helping.

`flutter doctor` shows

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76,
    locale en-US) 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace/`, clean build dir

[image]

2. I also  restarted the phone, but not sure if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i solved it by disconnecting my phone from the `Wifi`

Answer (score 1):

just uninstall your already installed apk and build it again thats how i solved my error on android device

Comment: Please also explain what the problem is and why your solution can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Get in terminal
2. Command: `lsof -nP -i4TCP:1024`

This command will return:

> COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> mobiledev 18230 mauro 7u IPv4 0xbea54bcdd5cea723 0t0 TCP 127.0.0.1:1024 (LISTEN)

3. Kill the mobiledev with the command `kill 18230` (the number PID from the process)
4. Hit the <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> or Start Debugging/Start Without Debuggin on VS Code or Android Studio
5. You have it working perfectly with hot reload, debug tools (breakpoints, watch variables, etc) and DevTools.

Reference
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32651

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input:

1. I did what you indicated (in xcode).
2. Later, I disconnected the device.
3. Again, I run the application in the terminal.

[image: Terminal Results]

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the same error. In my case, the issue was I have pointed to a wrong source for the image to be shown in the splash screen in the XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I changed my channel to dev and also ran the following commands and it solved it:

1: pod install

2: pod repo update

3: sudo gem install cocoapods

4: pod setup

Comment: Please also explain what the problem is and why your solution can solve the problem.

Comment: back then i was having exact same problem as OP, "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1024" and the above mentioned steps helped me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my physical Android device on Mac, but performing complete restart to my Mac had solved the problem.
N.B: Disabling VPN - if you use one - may helps to solve the issue.